# I tried make a bubble sort with C but it's not working (It's doing bubble sort 10 times)

Tags: c

first i giving how many numbers will i enter then i enter numbers. he need make bubble sort to them but its writing like======>
1 3 2 6 = 0 0 0 0(but it must be like 1 2 3 6(small to big))

the app how i want=

```
7

1 5 2 7 4 7 3

1 2 3 4 5 7 7
```

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int numbers[500000];
    int counter=0;
    int howmany;

    scanf("%d",&howmany);//getting how many numbers will we enter
    int howmany2=howmany;//we will use this for write all numbers after all

    while(howmany>0)//getting all numbers
    {
        scanf("%d",&numbers[counter]);
        howmany--;
        counter++;
    }

    int checker1,checker2;//its gonna check first and second number, then second and third...etc
    int hm=howmany-1;//its gonna check entered number-1 times(1,2,3)={1,2},{2,3}
    int clone1;//later we will copy numbers[checker1]
    int tentime=10;//we gonna do bubble sort 10 times

    while(tentime>0)//doing bubble sort
    {
        checker1=0;
        checker2=1;

        while(hm>0)
        {
            if(numbers[checker1]>numbers[checker2])
            {
                clone1=numbers[checker1];
                numbers[checker1]=numbers[checker2];
                numbers[checker2]=clone1;
            }

            checker1++;
            checker2++;
            hm--;
        }

    tentime--;
    }

    int counter2=0;

    while(howmany2>0)//showing new number sort on screen
    {
        printf("%d ",numbers[counter]);
        howmany2--;
        counter2++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Are you really expecting `500000` numbers to be entered from `stdin`? You are risking overflowing the such with such a big local arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- At the end of your first while loop howmany will be 0.  As a result hm will be set to -1 and the sort loop (while hm > 0 ) will never run.
- When you print out the results are using counter as the array index (this is 4 which is out of bounds and never changes since you are incrementing counter2.  As a result you are printing out an undefined value (0 in your case) four times.
- Declaring an array of size 500000 may blow up your stack.  Even if not it is way larger than you need